# php: replace tag html

Tags: php, string, replace

I would like to replace tag html

```
<p>Lundium purus ac nec! Enim porta cras! Elementum adipiscing vel mauris lundium! Et platea porta! Enim auctor nec enim enim nisi vel aliquet, odio! Mid. Facilisis.</p>
<p class="class_no">Lundium purus ac nec! Enim porta cras! Elementum adipiscing vel mauris lundium! Et platea porta! Enim auctor nec enim enim nisi vel aliquet, odio! Mid. Facilisis.</p>
```

to be like this

```
Lundium purus ac nec! Enim porta cras! Elementum adipiscing vel mauris lundium! Et platea porta! Enim auctor nec enim enim nisi vel aliquet, odio! Mid. Facilisis.<br/>
Lundium purus ac nec! Enim porta cras! Elementum adipiscing vel mauris lundium! Et platea porta! Enim auctor nec enim enim nisi vel aliquet, odio! Mid. Facilisis.<br/>
```

Is it possible?

Edit: I would like to replace all

```
<p *></p>
```

to be

```
<br />
```

Comment: Where is this html, in a string? If so, then you can use `strip_tags()` and/or `str_replace()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use also, JavaScript:

> `var spans = $('p');`
>
> `spans.contents().unwrap();`

Comment: You're welcome! Do not hesitate to contact me if you have any others questions! @user1128331

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not for HTML; but you can use PHP's function `strip_tags`, see: https://www.php.net/strip_tags - you can also specify tags to allow.

Comment: So I cannot change <p></p> to be <br/> just delete tag right?

Comment: You should use PHP's `DomDocument` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip_tags($string)` function for prevent html tags.

Answer (score 0):

If this html is in string then you can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
<?php
$string = '<p>Lundium purus ac nec! Enim porta cras! Elementum adipiscing vel mauris lundium! Et platea porta! Enim auctor nec enim enim nisi vel aliquet, odio! Mid. Facilisis.</p>
<p class="class_no">Lundium purus ac nec! Enim porta cras! Elementum adipiscing vel mauris lundium! Et platea porta! Enim auctor nec enim enim nisi vel aliquet, odio! Mid. Facilisis.</p>';

$to_be_replaced = array('%\<p(.)*?\>%', '%\</p\>%');
$replace    = array('',"<br/>");

echo preg_replace($to_be_replaced ,$replace, $string);

?>
```